# How do you call the functional pattern to get first non null result of applying function?

Tags: function, functional-programming

Is there a 'canonical' name for a function that would:

- receive a collection and a function
- iterate over a collection
- for each element, call the function
- if the function returns a non-null value, stop the iteration and return this value
- otherwise keep going

Ideally, the 'function' should be called at most once per element.

Example implementation (feels a bit clunky)

```
// xs : collection of type 'a
// f  : function from type 'a to type 'b
// returns : an element of type 'b, or nothing
function what_is_in_a_name(xs, f) {
  var res = null;
  _.find(function (item) {
    res = f(item);
    return res !== null;
  });
  return res;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like it could be implemented similar to a function called something like `firstThat`, where first takes as arguments a collection and a function that returns a boolean, and returns the first element which satisfies the predicate.  In Haskell,

```
firstThat :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> a
firstThat f (x:xs)
   | f x == True = x --returns the item
   | otherwise = first f xs
```

This is not 100% what you are looking for, but can be modified to do the job (in your language of choice that has `null` values of course!).

Comment: Well, type 'b could be replaced with (Maybe 'b) or something, I guess... but 'first' means 'first element of the collection' to most people, doesn't it ?

Comment: Yeah, I will edit my answer to be a bit clearer in that regard. I think a better name may be firstThat.  And yes, you could do a check that the return value is Just something.

Answer (score 0):

As you've already found, it can be decomposed to the common pattern „find the first element in a collection which satisfies a predicate“ for which there is a function in almost any language (like, `find_if` in C++ or `find` in Haskell). Then it can be combined with another helper functions to use the result of the passed function, like in this Haskell snippet:

```
firstApply :: (a -> Maybe b) -> [a] -> Maybe b
firstApply f = fmap f . find (isJust . f)
--or
firstApply f = join . find isJust . map f
--or
firstApply f = mconcat . map f
```

Without that, you could also do the task the manual way, like @zcleghern did. The imperative variant would fit this description too, differences are in the implementation only. In a mostly imperative language you would probably traverse the collection with loops, in a pure functional one — with recursion.

Your implementation is a mix of both ways: high-ordered `find` with closure (res) from FP, mutable reference and manual case handling from IP.

Knowing a lot about FP, you can also formulate the task in terms of a more general or abstract one (e.g., this function can be considered a special case of catamorphisms, or foldings), but I guess it would be an unnecessary overcomplication.

Comment: Just to make sure, isn't the 'f' function applied twice in some of your examples ? (I will edit my question to clarify that I'm trying to avoid it.)

Comment: @phtrivier only in the first one.